# Is there a way to extract html comment(s) using Selenium / WebDriver?

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver

The web app I need to test is made up of frames and has an HTML comment (`<!-- some text -->`)  at the end which will be present when the page finishes loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the pagesource and check if the comment is there

```
 _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://mysite.com");
  var source = _driver.PageSource;
  //check the source of the page to see if the commet is there.
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that, looks like I have to do driver.switchTo().frame("theFrame") to read in each frame. I think the best method for me is just checking a specific element is on each frame to make sure the page is fully loaded. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Comment elements are available in the DOM if the browser you're using makes them available.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XPath selector and JavaScriptExecutor to get all comment nodes:

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();          

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 

String sText =  js.executeScript("return document.evaluate(//comment, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)").toString();
```

then store the data as desired.

**References**

- [Selenium JavaDoc: JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)
- [MDN: document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)
- [Selenium JavaDoc: org.openqa.selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/package-summary.html)
- [Selenium Python Bindings: Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)
- [selenium-webdriver | RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver/)
- [Selenium::Remote::Driver - Perl Client for Selenium Remote Driver - metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver)